# Can't populate a JList from a TXT File

Tags: java, swing, file, jlist

Here's my working code that reads a TXT File and shows it in the console:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JList;

public class LeerArchivoDeTexto {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File archivo = new File("Archivo.txt");
        BufferedReader lector = null;
        DefaultListModel lista = new DefaultListModel();
        JList jList1 = new JList();

        try {
            lector = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo));
            String texto = null;

            while ((texto = lector.readLine()) != null) {
                lista.addElement(texto);
                System.out.println(texto);
            }
            jList1.setModel(lista);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (lector != null) {
                    lector.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The thing is that I want to load the data I have in my TXT File to a `JList`. The commented lines which envolve the `JList` aren't working. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you always define what 'Not working' means and include any exceptions or error messages you are getting.

Comment: Thanks jzd, I'll do that next time. :)

Comment: I keep getting a NullPointerException on `jList1.setModel(lista);`

Comment: You now added the line `jList1 = null;` which must not be there.

Answer (score 6):

The `JList` is not instantiated because you explicitly set it to null:

```
JList JList1 = null; // not initialized
```

So when trying to set the model to it I assume you get a `NullPointerException` on this line:

```
JList1.setModel(lista); // NPE here
```

You need to instantiate the `JList` and set the model to it like this:

```
JList jList1 = new JList();
jList1.setModel(lista);
```

Comment: Thank you eQui. Yes, I was getting a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

If you constract the JList correctly via

```
JList JList1 = new JList();
```

you can uncomment all your lines and it will work fine. Of course you then have to add this list to a swing container.

Comment: Thanks Howard, I'm going to give it a try!

Comment: Do you know how to add the list to a Swing container? I keep getting a NullPointerException on `jList1.setModel(lista);`

Comment: @Sam You can find tutorials [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) and especially [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for JList.

Comment: @Sam you added the line `jList1 = null;` which should not be there.

Comment: Great! It's working now! I'll check out your links. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You never create a new instance of a `JList` that is asigned to `JList1`, yet you are trying to call a method on that variable and most likely get a `NullPointerException`.

Instead of assigning null to `JList1`, assign a new instance.